# Running programs w/ a GUI over a remote connection

Tags: python, user-interface, ssh, perfmon

I'm trying to start perfmon and another program that have GUI's through a python script that uses a PKA ssh connection. Is it possible to do this? If so could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What platform is the GUI on?  Windows?  X-windows?  Other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a program called psexec that will open a program remotely on another windows machine. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx
There are options or flags that you can use with this command line program to open a program with a GUI and view it on a remote machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean [this](http://perfmon.sourceforge.net/) perfmon (the one that runs under Linux &c == I believe there's a honomym program that's Windows-only and would behave very differently), `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y` let you open an ssh connection which tunnels an X11 (GUI) connection (if server and client are both configured to allow that, of course).

[Here](http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/XoverSSH/X-over-SSH2.html) are copious details of how to do it "the old way" (with `-p` etc); [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-tunneling-xwindows-securely-over-ssh/), the explanation of `-X` and the more secure `-Y` modern options. As long as the app is running on a Linux box, you can have the display ("X Server") just about anywhere, with a proper ssh tunnel securely connecting them.

If it's Windows you're talking about (i.e. running the *perfmon app* on a Windows box, wherever it is you want the GUI), I don't know how to tunnel a GUI over ssh (it may not be possible). One possibility is [VNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.html) (there are several implementations of the protocol, both commercial and free) but I'm not all that experienced with it.

Comment: It is possible to run an X server on Windows and use it to run GUI apps from a Linux server that you've SSH'd into. But the other way around? I'm guessing not possible :-/

Comment: Right @David, that's what I meant -- let me edit and clarify!